# API Response is padded with weird characters

Tags: php, api, encoding

I found an API that returns a random dictionary word.

```
http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php
```

Although I run a

```
file_get_contents("http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php")
```

the response I receive is:

```
ï»¿antitragal
```

What are these characters that are prepended to the string ?

Comment: possibly a character encoding issue?

Answer (score 4):

Thats a UTF-8 BOM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark